# Fastest DCT? (With permissive license)

Tags: fft, dct

Does anyone know what is the fastest current algorithm/library for DCT I, II and III? I need a 2D real to real ordered implementation that can work with large matrices like 2048x2048. Most of the algorithms I find work only with 8x8 blocks, I am aware that FFTW can do a good job using the real to half complex algorithm but its license is not suitable for my project. I am just struggling to find anything else out there that is fast and stable, I am not sure about ooura, it seems a bit slow looking at the benchmark.

Comment: Is this a pure DCT you are looking for? JPEG implementations can combine steps with the DCT. What system? Do you need floating point or can you use scaled integers?

Comment: I need only floating point and N size, power of 2 is fine. Like fftw's fftwf_plan_r2r_2d(..., FFTW_REDFT10)